# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in line

Tags: php, mysql, database, phalcon

```
 class ABC extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
    {
        public $db;
        public function initialize()
        {
            $this->db=$this->getDi()->getShared('db');
        }
        public function getRows($role,$id)
        {
            $sql = "select *  from table where id=".$id;
            //echo $sql;  //exit;  
            //when i echo and execute the above query in db it is hsowing results fine.
            $connection = $this->db;
            $data       = $connection->prepare($sql);    //throwing error in this line 277 line
        }
    }
```

how can i debug this error:

i have other functions and for them db connection is working..!

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/site/admin/app/models/modelname.php on line 277

This my Di:

```
 //Create a DI
    $di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

    $di->set('db', function() {

        $eventsManager = new \Phalcon\Events\Manager();

        //Listen all the database events
        /*  $eventsManager->attach('db', function($event, $connection) {
              if ($event->getType() == 'beforeQuery') {
                  echo '<div>'.$connection->getSQLStatement().'</div>';
              }
          });*/

        $connection = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
            "host" => DBServer,
            "username" =>DBUsername,
            "password" => DBPwd,
            "dbname" =>DBName,
            "options" => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
            )
        ));

        //Assign the eventsManager to the db adapter instance
        $connection->setEventsManager($eventsManager);
       return $connection;
    });
```

Comment: Just making sure, are you calling the initialize() function **prior** to calling getRows()? What's var_dump($connection) outputs?

Comment: Instead of `$data       = $connection->prepare($sql); ` why won't you use `$data       = $this->db->prepare($sql); `

Comment: What is `$this->getDi()->getShared('db');`? Try dumping that to see what the db object is becoming.

Comment: So actually this line `$this->db=$this->getDi()->getShared('db');` itself not working. try to debug this line and check the issue

Comment: If you want to find the bug, you need to debug. Start with: "What's var_dump($connection) outputs?" for a regular case (when it works) and for the buggy case (when it doesn't).

Comment: And for the case when it does work?

Comment: Since the value is NULL, the problem lays deeper - You'll have to add the code of: getDi() and getShared('db').

Comment: I don't know Phalcon at all but having a quick look at the docs, maybe you should be using `setShared` instead of `set` if you intend to use `getShared`.